# Very tricky radius of convergence involving a non-monotonic summand,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Edit:  hints or solutions are welcome.

This question is something weird that I have not seen before, so I don't have much of a starting point - hadamard's radius of convergence formula also doesn't seem helpful.  The series is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(\alpha(\sqrt{1+n^2}))z^n$$

The two-part question is:

*What is the radius of convergence if $\alpha$ is any real number?  What if $\alpha$ is a complex number?*

This is an old complex analysis test question, so I think the square root is complex whether $\alpha$  is real or complex.

Thanks,

Comment: I would start by investigating whether $\cos(\alpha(\sqrt{1+n^2}))$ tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Hi @uniquesolution ...doesn't it just...oscillate with higher and higher frequency for non-zero $\alpha$ (real or complex)...?  Looking at cosine's exponential form doesn't really add any insight either ... hmm ...

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for real $\alpha$:

Since $|\cos(\alpha\sqrt{n^2 + 1})| \leq 1$ for all $n$, the radius of convergence is at least $1$.

To show it's exactly $1$, show that the terms when $z = 1$ don't go to zero.
For this, show that $|\cos(\alpha\sqrt{n^2 + 1})| \sim |\cos(\alpha n)|$ and that the
$\alpha n$ repeatedly go near multiples of $\pi$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: That's only for real $\alpha$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, it's different.

Comment: I should have said I was just doing the real case.

Comment: Hi @Zarrax how do you know that the radius of convergence is at least one?  Are you using Hadamard's formula $\frac {1}{limsup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$?

Comment: @user282830 That will work, but more simply just the absolute value of the nth term is bounded by $|z|^n$ which sums to absolutely when $|z| < 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The problem was posed for $\alpha$ real.

Comment: Hi @zhw - the question is for both cases, $\alpha$ real or complex.  Thanks,